# How do I run godoc locally for a module?

Tags: go, go-modules, godoc

I'm trying to run `godoc` locally for a module but running into this error.

It looks to me like `godoc` relies on `go list`, but doesn't run `go list` in a module friendly manner.

```
ak/ (master)  godoc -http=localhost:6060
using module mode; GOMOD=/Users/aaron/ak/go.mod
failed to determine the build list of the main module: go command exited unsuccessfully: exit status 1
go list -m: can't compute 'all' using the vendor directory
    (Use -mod=mod or -mod=readonly to bypass.)
```

Comment: As of now, that is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
GO111MODULE=off godoc
```

Looks like there's an ongoing issue with this: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/33655

For now, I've put this in my dotfiles:

```
alias godoc='GO111MODULE=off godoc'
```